# classloader extends from URLClassloader NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to write my own classloader. Here is my classloader code.

```
package server;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class MyClassloader extends URLClassLoader {

    public MyClassloader(URL[] urls) {
        super(urls);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> aClass = super.findClass(name);

        if (aClass == null) {
            return this.getParent().loadClass(name);
        }

        return aClass;
    }
}
```

And there is a blank class as the test class to be loaded.

```
package server;

public class MyClass {}
```

And the entry point main is

```
package server;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        // the dir that the compiled class file located in.
        File file = new File("/Users/mrd2242/Desktop/javatest/testedClass/");

        MyClassloader myClassloader = new MyClassloader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
        Class<?> myClass = myClassloader.loadClass("server.MyClass");

    }
}
```

As the comments showed above, first, I compile `MyClass` to `MyClass.class`. Then I move it to a directory `/Users/mrd2242/Desktop/javatest/testedClass/`, (Notice that this class has package name, so the absolute path of the .class file is `/Users/mrd2242/Desktop/javatest/testedClass/server/MyClass.class` .) and then pass the URL of this directory to the constructor of  `MyClassloader`.

Run the code but it failed. The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at server.MyClassloader.loadClass(MyClassloader.java:14)
    at server.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Object
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at server.MyClassloader.loadClass(MyClassloader.java:14)
    ... 10 more
```

From my perspective, this is so confuse. I override the `loadClass` method, in order to

1. First load class from a giving url using `URLClassLoader`'s `findClass` method.
2. If 1 failed, use the parent classloader's `loadClass` method to perform a normal class load process.

But the exception seems report that `java/lang/Object` is not found. What happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClassloader extends URLClassLoader {

    public MyClassloader(URL[] urls) {
        super(urls);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class<?> aClass = super.findClass(name);
            return aClass;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return this.getParent().loadClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I move the failure logic to a try block. Is this right?